# Is it possible to make a dynamic GET request with Axios params?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I need to query a a MySQL database based on one or more inputs from the client. In order to test this functionality, I am trying to query within my GET request based on only one input.

For starters, here is the code within my functional React component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function LookupResult(props) {

    const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/customer/lookup", {
            name: "Timmy Test"
        })
            .then(response => {
                setCustomerList(response.data)
                console.log(customerList)
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Lookup Table</h1>
            {customerList.map(customer => (
                <p key={customer.id}>
                    {customer.full_name}
                </p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default LookupResult;
```

I will eventually replace "Timmy Test" in `name: "Timmy Test"` with a prop from the parent component once I can access that name parameter on the server side.

On the server side, this is my current code:

```
app.get("/customer/lookup", (req, res) => {

    const name = "Timmy Test";

    const sqlSelect =
        "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE full_name = ?";
    db.query(sqlSelect, [name], (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.json(result);
            // console.log(result);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

I am aiming to then replace "Timmy Test" in the get request with the same prop/parameter from the React component.

How then do I pass that parameter from the axios.get request in my React component to the app.get request in my server side code?

Am I even correct in my approach to this problem, or is there a better way? Keep in mind, I will need to eventually query my SQL database using one of multiple possible inputs AND sometimes more than just one input too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stateful variable and make sure your effect is dependent on it to run. In this case, I'm using the `name` variable. You can use `setName` to change the value of the `name` variable and your effect will re-run.

```
const [name, setName] = useState("Timmy Test")

useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:4000/customer/lookup", {
      params: { name }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
      console.log(customerList);
    });
}, [name]);
```

Comment: I think that solves one problem, but how do I then access that name parameter on the server side?

Comment: You should be able to get it at `req.params.name`, let me know if that works!

Comment: Without changing
`axios.get("http://localhost:4000/customer/lookup", {
            name: "Timmy Test"
        })` 

I updated my server side to code to `const name = req.params.name;` and that did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @cchau whoops, looks like axios needs the params formatted as `{ params: { name: "Timmy Test" } }`. I updated my response, give that a shot!

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either unfortunately. The server doesn't recognize the `req.params.name`

Is there another way to go about this problem?

Comment: Just looked it up, it’s actually in the query params so try req.query.name